# Check if WinSCP downloaded files for every day between two dates

Tags: powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have this script to collect logs file between two dates. Normally I have logs created for everyday on remote machine but is there any possibility to show what file exist or not?

For example If I try to download file between two dates 25.06 - 30.06 and on remote machine doesn't exist log from 28.06 print in console.

> 25.06,26.06,27.06,29.06,30.06 log downloaded successfully
> [!] warning 28.06 log doesn't exist on remote machine!

```
# Set up session options
$options = @{
    Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp
    HostName = $entry.IP
    UserName = $User
    Password = $Password
    GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAnySshHostKey = $true
}

try {
    # Set up session options using first password
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property $options
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
    # Try Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)
} 
catch {
    # Set up session options using second settings
    $options['HostName'] = $vpnIP
    $options['UserName'] = $User
    $options['Password'] = $Password
    try {
        $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property $options
        $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session
        # Try Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Could not open WinSCP session: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        throw
    }
}

# Date 1 START
do {
    $date = $null
    $today = Read-Host -Prompt ('Enter START date (inclusive) (e.g. {0}) [yyyy.MM.dd]' -f (Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd"))

    try {
        $date = Get-Date -Date $today -Format "yyyy-MM-dd" -ErrorAction Stop
        '[OK] {0} Valid date - OK!' -f $date
    }
    catch {
        '[X] {0} Invalid date!' -f $today
    }
}
until ($date)

# Date 2 STOP

do {
    $date1 = $null
    Write-Host "Add +1 day" -ForegroundColor Red
    $today1 = Read-Host -Prompt ('Enter END date (exclusive) (e.g. {0}) [yyyy.MM.dd]' -f (Get-Date -Format "yyyy.MM.dd"))

    try {
        $date1 = Get-Date -Date $today1 -Format "yyyy-MM-dd" -ErrorAction Stop
        '[OK] {0} Valid date - OK!' -f $date1
    }
    catch {
        '[X] {0} Invalid date!' -f $today1
    }
}
until ($date1)

# ----- Date END

$session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

$file = "*.log"
$localPath = "\temp_files" 
$remotePath = "/C:/log", "/C:/Back_up"

try {
    # Connect
    $session.Open($sessionOptions)

    # Check exists folder
    foreach ($remotePath in $remotePath)
{
    if ($session.FileExists($remotePath))
    {
        Write-Host "[OK] Folder '$remotePath' exist" -ForegroundColor Green

            # Transfer file
        Write-Host "[i] '$date' - '$date1' > '$inputID' downloading..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $session.GetFilesToDirectory($remotePath, $localPath, "*.log>=$date<=$date1").Check();

    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "[X] INFO: Folder: '$remotePath' doesn't exist" -ForegroundColor Red
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $session.Dispose()
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can analyze the list of transferred files returned by `Session.GetFilesToDirectory` to find out if there any download for all days in the range (you [know that already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76652701/850848)).

But imo, way easier would be to go day-by-day, downloading respective day logs separately and simply checking, if any log was downloaded at all.

```
$d = $date
while ($d -le $date1)
{
    $f = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    $start = $d.ToString($f)
    $end = $d.AddDays(1).ToString($f)
    $mask = "*.log>=$start<$end"
    Write-Host "Downloading logs for $start..."

    $transferResult = $session.GetFilesToDirectory($remotePath, $localPath, $mask)
    $transferResult.Check()

    $c = $transferResult.Transfers.Count
    if ($c -gt 0)
    {
        Write-Host "$c logs for $start were downloaded"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "NO logs for $start were downloaded"
    }

    $d = $d.AddDays(1)
}
```

The code assumes that `$date` and `$date1` are actual `DateTime` objects, not strings. So you need to remove the `-Format "yyyy-MM-dd"` from the `Get-Date` calls.